# How does Rails implement the "date magic" mechanism on numbers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails (but not plain Ruby) one can say things like:

```
t = 2.days
t.inspect
```

=> "2 days"

```
t.to_i
```

=> 172800

It appears like Rails patched Fixnum so it stashes the number of seconds represented by the interval and the inspect string with a description.  Is this basically how it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveSupport has core extensions to base Ruby classes such as string, object, and Numeric that make this possible.

More here on the rails guides: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#time

ActiveSupport is adding the "days" to a number, and doing a calculation to give you

Code: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/time.rb

It's very basic though:

- 1 day is 24 hours
- 1 hour is 60 minutes